# glibc-locale error in yocto project with openstlinux distribution

Tags: stm32, yocto, glibc

I am working yocto project. I started with a custom board based on stm32mp157. You can find the board description in this link  [custom board](https://www.emtrion.de/de/products/emsbc-argon-single-board-computer.html). Vendor has a board support package in dunfell version. But I am doing my project in kirkstone version. I have choosen my distribution packgae from the openstlinuxdistribution. I have following build configuration for creating the image:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.0.0" 
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-emt_eglfs-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "emsbc-argon"
DISTRO               = "emt-eglfs"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "1.3"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
DISTRO_CODENAME      = "kirkstone"
ACCEPT_EULA_emsbc-argon = "1"
GCCVERSION           = "11.%"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-stm32mp-argon"
meta-emtrion-emsbc-argon 
meta-emtrion         = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
meta                 = "HEAD:f7766da462905ec67bf549d46b8017be36cd5b2a"
meta-oe              
meta-initramfs       
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          
meta-networking      
meta-webserver       
meta-filesystems     
meta-perl            = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:5b71df60e523423b9df6793de9387f87a149ac42"
meta-st-stm32mp      = "HEAD:ca501bd7dbe023682903ceedddaacd940b0898f4"
meta-st-openstlinux  = "HEAD:cb736b403d0fef2a02390695613b6b4bb13ca1b7"
meta-gnome           = "HEAD:05dcac98473402d87e0af73bbc2c5a6a840abe93"
```

I have created two custom layer, which added in the bblayers.conf file. I have the following error:

Summary: 1 task failed:
virtual:nativesdk:/home/hico/work/emtrion/argon-yocto/test-st-yocto/layers/openembedded-
core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc-locale_2.35.bb:do_package

You can find the log file in this link [logfile](https://pastebin.com/iewEFmud). Does anyone have any idea to solve this error?

Comment: Have you changed any `cleandirs` variable/flag in any of recipes in your layers?

Comment: I did not change any cleandirs variable/flag in any of my recipe. later I deleted the tmp folder and rebuild it again, then I did not have the glibc error, now I am having different error.